# How to update an Nested array using react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

PLZ help me, I'am stuck with problem now in my code

MY ARRAY IS

```
   const Addons = [
     {
      id: 1,
      SectionName: "AddOns",
      items: [
        {
          id: 494,
          name: "Cheese",
          price: "1.0",
        },

    {
      id: 434,
      name: "Bacon",
      price: 2.0,
    },

    {
      id: 484,
      name: "Onion",
      price: 3.0,
    },
  ],
},

{
  id: 2,
  SectionName: "BreadSelection",
  items: [
    {
      id: 155,
      name: "Wheat",
    },

    {
      id: 165,
      name: "Whole Grain",
    },
  ],
},

{
  id: 3,
  SectionName: "Topping",
  items: [
    {
      id: 175,
      name: "Caremelized Onion",
    },

    {
      id: 185,
      name: "Tomatoes",
    },
    {
      id: 195,
      name: "Letues",
    },
  ],
},
```

];

```
const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState("AddOns");
```

I just want to update the **items** array in the **Addons**
so that there will be an new field in **items** array as follows

```
 items: [
    {
      id: 175,
      name: "Caremelized Onion",
      checked:"true",
    },

    {
      id: 185,
      name: "Tomatoes",
    },
    {
      id: 195,
      name: "Letues",
    },
  ],
```

a new object **checked** forms there

the main goal of this is the check un check items selected so if the item is selected the *checked:"true"* else *checked:"false"*

Comment: `items: [ { id: 175, name: "Caremelized Onion", checked:"true", }, ......]` <-- here, `items` is an Array (of objects). The first element in `items` Array is an object. This object has props `id`, `name`, `checked`. The objective here is to add the prop `checked` to all elements of the `items` Array - or only to the first element?

Comment: all elements in the array

Answer (score 0):

This should get a new Addons array such that each element in the `items` array will have a `checked` flag.

```
const newAddons = Addons.map(ad => ({
  ...ad,
  items: ad.items.map(it => ({
    ...it,
    checked: it?.checked || false
  }))
}));
```

**Explanation**

- Use `.map` to iterate over the `Addons` array.
- Spread existing props of addon `ad` first
- Now, override `items` prop using `ad.items.map`
- For each element in the `items` array, add `checked` flag
- If there is an existing `checked` flag, use the value; else, set it to `false`.

**Code Snippet**

```js
 const Addons = [
     {
      id: 1,
      SectionName: "AddOns",
      items: [
        {
          id: 494,
          name: "Cheese",
          price: "1.0",
        },

    {
      id: 434,
      name: "Bacon",
      price: 2.0,
    },

    {
      id: 484,
      name: "Onion",
      price: 3.0,
    },
  ],
},

{
  id: 2,
  SectionName: "BreadSelection",
  items: [
    {
      id: 155,
      name: "Wheat",
    },

    {
      id: 165,
      name: "Whole Grain",
    },
  ],
},

{
  id: 3,
  SectionName: "Topping",
  items: [
    {
      id: 175,
      name: "Caremelized Onion",
      checked: true
    },

    {
      id: 185,
      name: "Tomatoes",
    },
    {
      id: 195,
      name: "Letues",
    },
  ],
}
];

const newAddons = Addons.map(ad => ({
  ...ad,
  items: ad.items.map(it => ({
    ...it,
    checked: it.checked || false
  }))
}));

console.log(newAddons)
```

**Usage**

When any option is selected/checked, use the Addons index (`adIdx`) and the corresponding item index (`itIdx`) to set the checked flag like so:

```
newAddons[adIdx][itIdx].checked = !newAddons[adIdx][itIdx].checked;
```

To directly update it on the state, use like so:

```
setAddons(prev => { prev[adIdx}[itIdx].checked = !prev[adIdx}[itIdx].checked); return prev });
```